# Number remapping to change usort order causes seemingly random sort

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I attempting to order an array of player characters (in a game) by class type. The class of each player is represented by a number. I would rather the classes be arranged in alphabetical order rather than numerically based on how my data defines each class.

My code is this:

```
$AlphabeticalClass = array(
    1 => 11,
    2 => 6,
    3 => 3, 
    4 => 8,
    5 => 7,
    6 => 1,
    7 => 9,
    8 => 4,
    9 => 10,
    10 => 5,
    11 => 2,
);

function CharacterSort($Char1, $Char2)
{
    $c1 = $Char1['character']['class'];
    $c2 = $Char2['character']['class'];

    //$c1 = $AlphabeticalClass[$c1];
    //$c2 = $AlphabeticalClass[$c2];

    return strcmp($c1, $c2);
}
```

When the comments are there, the sort happens perfectly (albeit ordering classes in a way I do not want):

[image: Sorting working]

When the comments are removed so that class revalues are remapped to be in alphabetical order:

[image: Sorting not working]

As you can see above, the class sorting has been thrown out of the window. Any ideas at all as to what is causing this?

The `usort` is applied to an array that organises data like so:

[image: Array of data]

Answer (score 0):

If class is numeric you might want to use `-` instead of `strcmp()`:

```
function CharacterSort($Char1, $Char2) {
    $c1 = $Char1['character']['class'];
    $c2 = $Char2['character']['class'];

    return $c1 -$c2;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CXCBKE)

Comment: You've submitted this as an answer so I'm not sure if this is just a general note. This did not fix the problem.

Comment: @Joe looking at your array data (the image above), it is a number right?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of here: http://dev.converge.guild.com/index.php?page=roster

Comment: sorry @Joe 404 not found / or maybe i'm authorized anyway

Comment: Note: A lot of the data is filtered out for display.

Comment: @Joe i don't see anything special, just looks the same structure as the one i have created http://codepad.viper-7.com/qBfx2a

Comment: @Joe i'm just wondering, why are you sorting them alphanumerically by class if class is an integer? doesn't really make sense

Comment: The integer of class refers to a string of the class name. I want it ordered in that way. Your code does not address the problem: the fact the remapping array $AlphabeticalClass results in the order appearing to be random.

Comment: @Joe then, you need to put the equivalent class name that represents that number? is it inside the arrays? is this from a select, maybe you need another join to get that name

Comment: I tried to convert the class integer to the string equivalent and sort using the string but that resulted in exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Joe now if `[class] => Rogue or [class] => Warrior`, then you can use `strcmp($c1, $c2);`